# Avoid null check correctly

Tags: scala, for-loop, null, nullpointerexception, monads

I am trying to build generaziled for loop. Every function like func1, func2, func3 may return Some or None.

```
def func1(in: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  return in
}

def func2(in: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  return in
}

def func3(in: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  return in
}


val res = for {
  x <- List(Some("hello"), None, Some("world"))
  y <- func1(x)
  z <- func2(y)
  w <- func3(z)
} yield w

print(res)
```

The purpose is avoid null checks completely.

But the following error doesn't allow me to pass argument into the first call

```
 found   : String
 required: Option[String]
  z <- func2(y)
             ^
one error found
```

1. What is the corrent way to build chains like that?
2. How can I avoid to keep Option[String] argument in my functions. I want directly manipulate with String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option` trait aka `Maybe Monad` is tend to use with functions of type `x => Option[y]`. The   `for( <- ) yield` syntax sugar is replaced by compiler with corresponding `flatMap` calls which is equivalent for monadic `bind` operator.

So you are expected to use functions like `X => M[Y]` in `flatMap` and for-expression with `List`s\ `Option`s\ `Stream`s \ `Iterator`s etc.

Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)

Also your first expression has type `List[Option[X]]`. To extract values properly you could use intermediate value in [Vladimir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21216226/210905).

like

```
def func1(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}

def func2(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}

def func3(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}


val res = for {
  x <- List(Some("hello"), None, Some("world"))
  t <- x
  y <- func1(t)
  z <- func2(y)
  w <- func3(z)
} yield w

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly that - you do not need `funcX` argument to be `Option[String]`. Use just `String`:

```
def func1(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}

def func2(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}

def func3(in: String): Option[String] = {
  Some(in)
}


val res = for {
  x <- List(Some("hello"), None, Some("world"))
  y <- func1(x)
  z <- func2(y)
  w <- func3(z)
} yield w

print(res)
```

Comment: Already tried, it causes error: type `mismatch; found: Option[String] required: String` in func1 call

Comment: @tmporaries, ah, yes, I didn't recognize that `List` consists of `Option`s... The answer by Odomontois is correct on what to do.